# NUnit - ExpectedMessage differs error

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper, expected-exception

I am quite new to TDD and am going with NUnit and Moq. I have got a method where I expect an exception, so I wanted to play a little with the frameworks features.

My test code looks as follows:

```
    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(ExpectedException = typeof(MockException), ExpectedMessage = "Actual differs from expected")]
    public void Write_MessageLogWithCategoryInfoFail()
    {
        string message = "Info Test Message";

        Write_MessageLogWithCategory(message, "Info");

        _LogTest.Verify(writeMessage =>
            writeMessage.Info("This should fail"),
            "Actual differs from expected"
        );
    }
```

But I always receive the errormessage that the error message that the actual exception message differs from the expected message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which test runner are you using?

Comment: Hopping that I understood you correctly, I'm using NUnit version 2.5.1

Comment: and you are running your tests using nunit-gui.exe? Or you are running them from Visual Studio in some way?

Comment: I'm running them with the Resharper tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Resharper test runner has a bug/limitation - it doesn't handle the ExpectedException attributes. You have 2 options:

1. Use some other test runner (e.g. nunit-gui.exe, shipped with NUnit) - but this approach makes it a pain to debug your tests
2. Catch and validate the exception manually, using the following pattern:

   [Test]
   public void Write_MessageLogWithCategoryInfoFail()
   {
       try
       {
         string message = "Info Test Message";

   ```
     Write_MessageLogWithCategory(message, "Info");

     _LogTest.Verify(writeMessage =>
         writeMessage.Info("This should fail"),
         "Actual differs from expected"
     );
     Assert.Fail("Expected exception");
   }
   catch(MockException e)
   {
     Assert.AreEqual("Actual differs from expected", e.Message);
   }
   ```

   }

Its a real shame, because the descriptive way of saying that you expect an exception is much nicer!

On a side note I hope that the code above is only for playing with the framework - usually you would never catch MockExceptions :)

Comment: Thanks I tested your code and I think I know now why it never was equal. The message in the exception is larger due to a more detailed error message:

"Actual differs from expected\r\nInvocation was not performed on the mock: writeMessage => writeMessage.Info(\"This should fail\")"

But thanks for the hint! And even though this test runs over production code.. Yes I'm playing around with framework ;-)

Comment: I got a similar error running an NUnit test with TestDrivet.Net:
The exception message text was incorrect
Expected: Password_too_short
 but was: Password_too_short  EDIT: in my case the message was really different (continued after a line break)

Comment: @w0lf, you mean that there was a line break at the end of the exception message, but not in what you passed in TestDriven.NET?

Comment: @JenniferS Yes. I somehow saw the messages side-by-side in the NUnit output and they seemed equal. But then I figured it out...

Comment: The ReSharper Test runner as of today handles the attributes. I have version JetBrains ReSharper 7.1.3 C# Edition
Build 7.1.3000.2254 using Visual Studio 2010 (Version 10.0.40219.1)

Comment: @Grzenio Please consider my comment about ReSharper

Comment: @Marcel, they must have fixed it at last!

Answer (score 2):

You may use the extra parameter `MatchType = MessageMatch.Regex`.

Comment: think about providing additional explanation why do you think this will fix the issue. Also more details on how to apply your solution, probably a code snippet would be the best idea.

Comment: When using Resharper this doesn't help the problem.